# Zend cookie issue

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, cookies, multilingual

I'm working on a Zend 1.11 webapp. I built a language-selector plugin for switching language (it & en) depending on the user input.

This is what I have:

```
class LS_Controller_Plugin_LangSelector extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{


    if($request->getParam('lang'))
    {
        $lang=$request->getParam('lang');
        setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600));
        echo "we just set a cookie";    
    }
    else if (isset($_COOKIE['lang']))
    {
        $lang=$_COOKIE['lang']; 
        echo $lang;
    }
    else 
    {   echo 'We are here.But I can't understand why';
        $lang='en';
        var_dump($_COOKIE);
    }

    switch(strtolower($lang))
    {
        case 'en':
            $locale="en_US";
        break;

        case 'it':
            $locale="it_IT";
        break;

        default:
            $locale="en_US";
    }

    $zl=new Zend_Locale();
    $zl->setLocale($locale);

    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale',$zl);



    $translate=new Zend_Translate(
                  array(
                          'adapter' => 'gettext',
                          'content' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/languages/'.$locale.'.mo',
                          'locale'  => 'en'
                      )

    );

    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate',$translate);
}   

}
```

[bootstrap.php]

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

protected function _initRoutes()
{

    $frontController=Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router=$frontController->getRouter();  
    $router->removeDefaultRoutes();
    $router->setGlobalParam('lang','en');
    $router->addRoute(
            'lang',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:lang/:controller/:action',
            array('lang'=>':lang',
            'module'=>'default',
            'controller'=>'index',
            'action'=>'index'

            )

            )
    );


    $router->addRoute(
    'langController',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:controller/:action',
    array(
            'module'=>'default',
            'controller'=>'index',
            'action'=>'index'
            )

    )
);

            $router->addRoute(
    'langIndex',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:lang',
    array('lang'=>':lang',
            'module'=>'default',
            'controller'=>'index',
            'action'=>'index'
            )

    )
);

            $router->addRoute(
    'langNothing',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('',
    array('lang'=>'en',
            'module'=>'default',
            'controller'=>'index',
            'action'=>'index'
            )

    )
);

}
}
```

The point is that:

- I type in my browser the full URL mysite.com/it/index/index and I get echo out "we just set a cookie"..wich is fine I should be able to browse my website with the italian cookie set but I don't. Whenever I click over a link (Ex. /index/contactus..links do not specify the 'lang' parameter!) I navigate to that page but it's in english again (I get echoed out the message:"we are here.but I can't understand why").

Shouldn't the cookie be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you don't specify the **path** for your cookie. So it will set for the **current page** only.

If you browse to another (sub)site, then your cookie is not valid for this path and doesnt get transmitted. You should set your lang-cookie to the "/" Path.

See [setcookie()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) documentation:

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. **The default value is the current directory** that the cookie is being set in.

Comment: +1. The fix is as simple as changing the setcookie line to `setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + 3600, '/');`

Comment: After I added as suggested the '/' in the setcookie line it was working perfectly.
Now (after laptop shutdown) i'm experimenting strange behaviour cause the setcookie set the lang-cookie = 'favicon.ico' but I don't know where this come from! can you help me? I added my bootstrap file in the question

Comment: @luca it is because of your "lang" route. as you set :controller and :action from the route, www.yoursite.de/favicon.ico (which the browser request to show the favicon) is matched and lang is setted to favicon.ico. So i'll guess, the first request your browser made was the favicon request, setting you a cookie with that value. A proof your code is not order-proof which shows bad design. An possible fix would be to remove the route and just add the lang as normal parameter (www.yoursite.de/some/query/string/value/lang/en)

Comment: I removed the call to favicon via htaccess for the moment and now it's working..I have to adjust the routes thanks youre super!